# Good Evaluation function for Game Playing Minmax Agent with Alpha Beta Pruning

Tags: artificial-intelligence, heuristics, alpha-beta-pruning, game-theory, minmax

I'm trying to build an AI agent for a specific zero-sum board game using alpha-beta pruning. The program will be depth limited because of certain time constraints and hence I need a good evaluation function to use. The game is as follows

> It is a two-player game in which each player tries to maximize his/her
>   share from a batch of candies randomly placed in a box. The box is
>   divided into cells and each cell is either empty or filled with one
>   candy of a specific type. At the beginning of each game, all cells are
>   filled with candies. Players play in turn and can pick a cell of the
>   box in their own turn and claim all candies of the same type, in all
>   cells that are connected to the selected cell through horizontal and
>   vertical paths. For each selection or move the agent is rewarded a
>   numeric value which is the square of the number of candies claimed in
>   that move. Once an agent picks the candies from the cells, their empty
>   place will be filled with other candies on top of them(which fall down
>   due to gravity), if any. In this game, no candy is added during
>   gameplay. Hence, players play until all candies have been claimed.

Given the above gameplay, can someone help me get a good eval function for the game ? One thought that comes to my mind is to get the maximum number of fruits that can be claimed from the given board state as a heuristic/eval function. However, this is not a great eval function. What could be better ?

Comment: Take a look at [binary image processing](http://cs.haifa.ac.il/hagit/courses/ip/Lectures/Ip13_Binary.pdf) and [connected-component labeling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling).

Comment: play against yourself (or another human) and after you learn to play, see what are *you* trying to maximize.  then you may want to make a program which plays against itself using two different evaluation functions, and check which evaluation function is better.

Comment: @user31264, I thought of this approach however, I don't have multiple eval functions with me right now. So was asking for suggestions. I can rank them for sure by playing the agent against itself

Comment: the most obvious eval function will be how many points each player scored already (the difference between their points).

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but the eval function ideally gives us a sense of how good the current state actually is. Using the scores two players have so far is no indication of that.

Comment: If I understood correctly, isn't the optimal move at each step simply to pick the cell that has the maximum reward, i.e. the cell that has the highest number of neighbouring cells of the same color? If so, you don't need an evaluation function nor minmax, as the optimaly strategy is clear.

Comment: @TheCodingMonk, it's not necessary that the cell giving you the max score is the best strategy. "Once an agent picks the candies from the cells, their empty place will be filled with other candies on top of them(which fall down due to gravity), if any." The gravity operation might give a higher combination in the future if we sacrifice the greedy approach now.